# ios10 custom push notification sound not playing

Tags: apple-push-notifications, ios10

I am currently running iOS 10 beta 8 with Xcode 8.0 beta 6 and the custom sound does not play when I receive a push notification with the correct payload.

I have verified the payload and it is in the correct format per the apple documentation:

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "You got your emails.",
        "badge" : 9,
        "sound" : "bingbong.aiff"
    },
    "acme1" : "bar",
    "acme2" : 42
}
```

When I send the same payload to the same build on iOS9 the custom sound plays properly.

Does anyone know if there are any other changes in iOS 10 that I need to make?

Comment: I've got the very same problem...anyone?

Comment: try to put content-available 0 maybe in iOS 10 have some bug and send content-available = 1 by default because some changes apply in push with iOS 10, or change the sound for other "chime.aiff"

Comment: Investing in this post. I've Xcode 8, and I'm seeing this too. Skype and other older apps are fine.

Comment: You need only reboot iPhone! No problem after with both debug build and AppStore app

Comment: @malex did you see this problem on the AppStore release before rebooting the phone? I'm waiting to release a new build of my app, but I'm experiencing this issue with the Test Flight build. Rebooting the phone does resolve the issue but I'm not satisfied with that as a solution.

Comment: I've got the same problem with a released app that is in the App Store. If users remove and reinstall the app the custom sound is played correctly when a notification is received. My guess is that it is an iOS 10 bug?

Comment: Having the same issue on Testflight running ios 10.0.2.

Comment: What is the frequency experienced by users? I have had one so far out of 15 external testflight users.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This problem seems to only affect apps installed via Xcode. The issue persists even if you later update the app from a different source.

The solution is to completely remove the app, and reinstall it from TestFlight or the App Store.

In effect, this bug should not affect your end users.

Edit 2016-10-15:

Unfortunately it seems that I was mistaken. This appears to be a bug on iOS 10 that can, in fact, affect App Store apps also. If it is of any consolation, apps such as Facebook and WhatsApp are affected too. The solution is apparently to [force restart your phone](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201559), but unfortunately there doesn't seem to be much we can do about it as developers.

**Apple Fixed Issue:**

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42495439/questions-about-push-notifications-sound-in-ios-10?noredirect=1#comment72214572_42495439) comment, Apple has seemed to fix the issue in **iOS 10.2**

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Would not have guessed! For others' reference, a TestFlight user of mine reported experiencing this issue, but App Store version was fine.

Comment: I am experiencing this issue when updating an App Store version of an app with the Test Flight version of the app. Rebooting the phone resolves the issue with the custom sounds not playing. Can anyone else confirm that if I push this release to the App Store, my customers won't be affected? I'd be hung out to dry if this issue was released into the wild!

Comment: Actually this solved my problem. Is there any official reference concerning this problem? Or did you just solved it by trial and error?

Comment: @binncheol, You just saved my day buddy. Thanks. We are planning to release version soon then will confirm you the status. And if you have already released your version, please update the status here. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @RahulVerma App was released and shows the same problem. Restarting the phone fixes it.

Comment: @binncheol Are you saying you've received reports of this issue from end-users who have only ever downloaded the app from the App Store? I have seen the issue myself two times already, but have not received any reports from my customers. Of course in my app, it's not as critical what the sound is as long as it plays reliably.

Comment: I'm having this issue even with App Store versions of my app. Be careful with that. The solution was to reboot device.

Comment: Rebooting the device is the solution to this. iOS 10.1 Beta 2+ fixes this issue

Comment: I'm confused is the solution **only** hard reboot OR it's uninstall + fresh install **and** also doing hard reboot?

Answer (score 4):

Try installing your app using Test Flight and after implementing initial process to update device token just restart your device.

You'll get what you have been looking for.

Credit goes to - [binncheol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1453155/binncheol)

Comment: We've got this issue on a normal AppStore App too. You can find similiar bug reports also for other apps (e.g. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7666549). I guess, its a general iOS10 bug. Restarting the iPhone/iPad brings back the correct notification tone.

Comment: @MrJ, Thanks for this additional information. I hope they will resolve this issue in next release soon.

Answer (score 3):

Having our user restart their device is correcting the issue for us.

This is an issue for us regardless of how the app was installed (TestFlight or from the app store).

Comment: Just to be sure...are you saying your solution was **only** hard reboot OR it was uninstall + fresh install **and** also doing hard reboot?

Comment: AFAIK, it was just the OS shutdown/restart.

Comment: And you only had to do it once? After that the issue never resurfaced?

Comment: This is all coming from our support department -- but yes, for this particular push notification issue, that's the word.

Answer (score 2):

There is definitely an iOS10 bug which still persists as of 10.0.2. It affects many apps including popular ones such as Whatsapp and Messenger. The workaround is just to power cycle the device, after which point the notification sounds are correct. It doesn't seem to matter how the app is installed.

I can't find any documentation of this from Apple (go figure) but there is more info here: http://thetechbeard.com/how-to-fix-notification-sound-problem-in-ios-10/.

As reported [here](http://forums.imore.com/ios-10/372588-ios-10-notification-sounds-messed-up.html) lots of other people are having this problem. Hopefully Apple fixes it soon.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled the app, turned off the real device, reinstall the app, and then the custom notification sound started working. It didn't work before I restarted my device XD