# Sound issues fixes for iOS 10 Push Notifications

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, ios10

I’ve implemented push notifications for our app.

on iOS 9, the sound words fine.
on iOS 10, it’s very unpredictable. Fresh install from Xcode on iOS 10.0.2 would bring up my *custom* sound. reinstall would bring up *default* sound. I don’t know exactly when but at times I also get *no* sound.

reading from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39400703/ios10-custom-push-notification-sound-not-playing) and many others my conclusion is that it works after a hard reboot. 2 questions:

- Has Apple completely fixed this issue in any version? If so what version?
- After a *hard* reboot, would the problem *completely* go away? Or you need to do it again? if so when?

Comment: If this is an iOS 10 bug (which it sounds like it is), have you considered opening a radar with Apple?  https://bugreport.apple.com/

Comment: @JAL It's already reported [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/63186) says "Engineering has determined that your bug report (28348721) is a duplicate of another issue (27968066) and will be closed."

Comment: Looks like it's a known issue.  Nothing we can do now expect wait for a response from Apple.  What you can do is duplicate and file an additional radar on your own Apple Developer Account and post to OpenRadar like I did here: [rdar://30758362](http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=5065100113215488).  That way, you let Apple know that this issue is important, since it received multiple reports.

Comment: Hey Honey, Apple replied to my bug report saying this issue was fixed in iOS 10.2 and to verify the fix in the 10.2.1 GM.  Can you try reproducing on a device on one of those iOS versions?

Comment: @JAL Awesome thanks for the update. "and to verify the fix in the 10.2.1 GM" <--what? Are you asking me if I can verify the fix on 10.2.1 GM?

Comment: GM generally means Golden Master.  Check with iOS 10.2.1 retail or if you have it, the Golden Master release candidate.

Comment: @JAL before asking this question I looked into the release notes of iOS releases from [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1893?locale=en_US) and didn't find anything from Apple. **Am I looking in the wrong place or Apple doesn't care?**. Give me some time and I'll try again and get back to you.

Comment: That seems like the right place, but it's also possible the bug was mentioned in pre-release Xcode or iOS version release notes, and potentially the iOS 10.2 API diffs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Has Apple completely fixed this issue in any version? If so what
>   version?

Based on [JAL's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42495439/questions-about-push-notifications-sound-in-ios-10/42540634#comment72214572_42495439) Apple has fixed in iOS 10.2.

> After a hard reboot, would the problem completely go away? Or you need
>   to do it again? if so when?

Based on [leontx's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39400703/ios10-custom-push-notification-sound-not-playing#comment72165405_40185507), For those users who are using iOS 10.0.x or 10.1.x they would only need to do a **single** hard reset.